# How to set custom formatting date in Android

Tags: android, android-calendar, realm

I want develop TODO-List application with Realm Database, this application user can set Title, Date and time for Task/Todo .

**my code is :** 

 *Dialog codes:*

```
// Calendar Class
Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
calender.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dialog_date.getDay());
calender.set(Calendar.MONTH, dialog_date.getMonth());
calender.set(Calendar.YEAR, dialog_date.getYear());
calender.set(Calendar.HOUR, dialog_date.getHour());
calender.set(Calendar.MINUTE, dialog_date.getMinute());

long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
Task_Provider task_provider = new Task_Provider(addTask, now, calender.getTimeInMillis(), false);

realm.beginTransaction();
realm.copyToRealm(task_provider);
realm.commitTransaction();
realm.close();
```

Adapter codes:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (holder instanceof TaskHolder) {
        TaskHolder taskHolder = (TaskHolder) holder;
        Task_Provider task_provider = mResults.get(position);
        taskHolder.setTask(task_provider.getTask());
        taskHolder.setDate(task_provider.getWhen_date());
        taskHolder.setBackground(task_provider.isComplete());

        mAdapter = new TaskAdapter(mContext, mRealm, mResults, mMarkListener);
    }
}
```

setDate method code :

```
    public void setDate(long when_date) {
        card_date.setText(DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(when_date, System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS, DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_ALL));
    }
}
```

My application result below image : 
[image: In my Application]

*But **i want** show date such as this image :* 
[image: I want this image]

How can i set formatting for Calendar date? tnx all <3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add to the top of your class:

```
private static SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Then your new `setDate()` will be:

```
public void setDate(long when_date) {
    card_date.setText(dateFormat .format(new Date(when_date)));
}
```

Comment: He probably wants `new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");`, but that's the idea